# How to install npm dependencies efficiently for multiple dockerized node.js projects in a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm, node-modules

I have a monorepo project, containing 10 packages let's say.
Each and every one of these packages has a `Dockerfile`, with a seprate `npm install` command. Each `npm install` command takes about 10 minutes on their own. Building all images takes 10 x 10 minutes, which is unacceptable.

**What I came up with so far**: Creating a `Dockerfile` where I copy the whole monorepo at the same time, do an `npm install` there, which takes only ~15 mins, since there's a lot of common depenendencies. From there I can just use this as the base image for all the other images. The only problem is, that this base image is 5 gigs, which is huge, because it ecapsulates the `node_modules` folder, which now contains ALL the dependencies from every project.

**Copying only necessary folders from node_modules ?** Is there a command in npm, that lists all the depdendencies for a `package.json` file (with all the peer dependendencies etc) so I can filter what I copy from the base image's node_modules folder to the final image (thus reducing size while not downloading common dependencies multiple times)? Maybe an already established tool that can do just that?

**Boundling node_modules ?**: Another idea I had is to bundle the app, which would only include in the finaly bundle the code the package actaully uses, so using multi-stage builds, the final image could be very small. This is what I'm already using with the frontend of the applicaiton (with Vite or CRA previously) but I have not managed to get it working for node.js. Presumably because pg-native might have some binaries, which can not be bundled. Nevertheless, it would be the BEST solution to bundle everything into a 5mb js file, and install only problematic dependencies afterwards like pg-native. I have not found any tutorial, description about this whatsoever, so I'm not terribly confident this can even be achieved, and I've got no clue ...why?

Ridiculously uneffective answers I've found so far include:

- **reducing dependencies** - its not possible, checked 3 times with `depcheck`
- **installing only the prod dependencies** - only saves a few mb-s nothing significant
- **using multi stage builds** - it's a good solution to start a fresh image, if you have build artifacts in the "builder" image, but in my case, it does not reduce the node_moduels size, only in the frontend image, because there the node_modules are bundle to a js file, and not necessary during runtime.
- **using node:x-alpine image** - using it already, it saves 500mb, but that's also insignificant compared to the 3-4gigs of node_modules I have to copy around everywhere.

Finally, a little explanation why this is important for me: I'm using Builx with a docker-container driver, which is necessary to take advantage of caching via gha or local caching types set via the --cache-to option. The docker-container driver has a very slow phase, called `sending tarball`, and it's directly related to image size. Downloading-uploading the cache from GHA-s cache storage is also very much effected by the cache size. So on paper, if we take ~600mb images, instead of ~4000mb images, the whole process could be speed up via 6-7x. That's a huge improvement, not even mentioning how cost effective that would be, since in the cloud everything is billed my seconds of computing power / storage used.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any feel for what part of the installation is slow – downloading artifacts, native compiles, the mechanics of `npm` itself?  Does Yarn do any better?  If you split this into a separate repository per application, does it parallelize better and can you avoid rebuilding the applications that haven't changed?

Comment: @DavidMaze Every part is slow on big projects, so I'd go with NPM itself. Pnpm, yarn the same. The problem is the lack of sharing the common dependencies, and downloading, linking, etc.. them separately. This has nothing to do with repositories really, the fundamentals don't change, the problem is more connected to how docker and monorepos don't play together well by design.